# Why would "this" in function inside angularjs service be undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, prototype, this

*Why would this inside function be undefined in angularjs service?*

```
.service('SliceService', function () {
    var self = this;

    var Slice = function(intervals, intervalSpan) {
        self.activeSlice = [];
        self.hasNext = true;
        self.hasPrevious = false;
        self.intervals = intervals;
        self.intervalSpan = intervalSpan;
    }

    Slice.prototype.findIntervalIndex = function (time, slice) {
        slice = slice || self.intervals;
        return _.findIndex(slice, function (o) {
            return o.time === time;
        });
    };

    return Slice;

})

.controller('myController', ['SliceService', function(SliceService) {
    SliceService([arr], 12);
    SliceService.findINtervalIndex(time);
}])
```

*In the above example when using it in a controller, this.activeSlice throws an error `TypeError: Cannot set property 'activeSlice' of undefined`.*

-

#### Update

Thanks, everyone! I've updated my example to better reflect what I'm trying to do. With the above I'm getting a `TypeError: SliceService.findIntervalIndex is not a function` — Also maybe a service is not fit for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I guess Angular doesn't call the function with `new` and does not set `this` to any other specific value? If a strict function is called "normally", such as in `foo()`, then `this` is `undefined`.

Comment: try browsing about bind and call functions in js

Answer (score 2):

**Try saving the value of "this" before accessing it inside the anonymous scope:**

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myServices').service('SliceService', function () {
        var context = this;

        var Slice = function(intervals, intervalSpan) {
            context.activeSlice = [];
            context.hasNext = true;
            context.hasPrevious = false;
            context.intervals = intervals;
            context.intervalSpan = intervalSpan;
        }

        return Slice;
    });
}());
```

**Using Bind:**

```
    angular.module('myServices').service('SliceService', function () {
        var Slice = function(intervals, intervalSpan) {
            this.activeSlice = [];
            this.hasNext = true;
            this.hasPrevious = false;
            this.intervals = intervals;
            this.intervalSpan = intervalSpan;
        }.bind(this);

        return Slice;
    });
```

**Note:**
using arrow function of javascript ES6 makes sure that *this* always points to the same context. so you could replace regular function with arrow function. This is however not universally supported without transpiling.

```
service('SliceService', ()=>{ 
 // operations
}
```

Comment: Agreed. The `bind` option is, however, a bad idea when considering performance. +1

Comment: Didn't know about the performance issue with bind, thanks for bringing that up.

Comment: Also, @Shawn Rieger your question is a pure JS question. You would face the same problem you have in plain Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @SeedyROM and some additional google searches on angular services. This solved all my issues...

```
angular.module('vpower.services').service('SliceService', function () {
    this.activeSlice = [];
    this.hasNext = true;
    this.hasPrevious = false;
    this.intervals = [];
    this.intervalSpan = 12;

    this.findIntervalIndex = function (time, slice) {
        var curTime;
        slice = slice || this.intervals;
        return _.findIndex(slice, function (o) {
                curTime = o.time._i || o.time;
            return curTime === time;
        });
    };
```

I think I was not fully understanding the way services work.